# What is the opposite of 'picky'?

Tags: word-request

What adjective would be used to describe an attitude where one is not too demanding about something (like the food they eat, the clothes they wear, etc.).

I'm looking for a word that sounds fairly informal or colloquial.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/picky

Comment: Not posting as an answer because you are specifically looking for another word and there are several valid answers here, but I would say that in my AmE experience simply "I'm not picky"/"(S)he's not picky" seems to be a very common informal/colloquial phrasing.

Comment: Can't share as an actual answer, but how about "Indifferent"?. Meaning unconcerned regarding the outcome. any of the available options are fine. I use it routinely myself when a group of friends are deciding where to go for food and ask for my opinion "Eh, I'm pretty indifferent, they're all good"

Comment: Apathetic. That would be my choice. It is more like uncaring though.

Comment: For what it's worth, one problem you'll run into with this topic is that we use different words to talk about ourselves and others. "I'm easy/open/game for..." versus "He's not demanding/fussy/particular about..." In general, we frame ourselves in terms of attitude and others in terms of how much of a pain they're being.

Comment: You should provide an example sentence or sentences with a blank where you want the adjective to go.

Comment: @user18894 What is the reason you want to know, if you can provide it? That could help us a lot, as answerers.

Comment: I dont have enough rep to post an answer - but "lax" might work. Lax means "Not sufficiently strict, severe, or careful."

Comment: *Unselective* ...

Answer (score 28):

I might use ***easygoing***, which is synonymous with *undemanding*. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/easygoing) lists it as any antonym of *fussy*, which can be applied to tastes in food or clothes.

One definition that fits this context is:

> **[easygoing](https://www.wordnik.com/words/easygoing)** (*adj*) relaxed and informal in attitude or standards

An example sentence might be:

> *Diane is really picky about what she eats, but her sister Jill is much more easygoing*.

An idiom that might work is ***go with the flow***, which Macmillan defines as:

> **[go with the flow](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/go-with-the-flow)** (*phrase*) do what seems like the easiest thing in a particular situation

This may not a precise fit, but it could work depending on what you were trying to convey:

> *Every time we go to the mall, Diane is really picky about clothes, but Jill just goes with the flow. She'll pretty much agree to anything we suggest*.

The phrase *go with the flow* suggests a calm and accepting attitude.

Comment: If you mean "picky" as in _willfully_ selective (i.e. not wanting to eat something rather than genuinely not liking it), then "open [to something]" can also be a workable antonym. Picky can be used in a few different cases (related as to how/why a certain option is discarded), which influences the correct antonym. This is similar to how the antonym of "man" can change with a different context: woman (gender), boy (maturity), mouse (courage), animal (civility), machine (organic/artificial)

Comment: More idiomatic to me would be "adventurous", especially with regard to food.

Comment: @AlexR - I agree; I think "adventurous" would be an excellent word to use, especially when one is trying a food they have never eaten before.

Comment: @J.R. - I can't add an answer of my own, but feel free to add it to yours if you like it :)

Comment: "Go with the flow" means you are happy to do what everybody else is doing. That can mean someone is agreeable and undemanding in general, but I don't see how that could apply to clothing. Would that mean wearing what other people want? Or wearing what everybody else is wearing?

Comment: @Astralbee - The example scenario I used here was when someone is clothes shopping. I don't think there's any one word that fully captures the exact sense the OP is looking for. I don’t even know what “picky about clothing” means. Only wears the latest styles? Only wears designer brands? Only wears cotton and never wool?

Comment: @J.R. How about *easy to please*?

Answer (score 28):

We can use **flexible**, which is often used casually.

Formally, this is defined as: *(of a person) ready and able to change so as to adapt to different circumstances.*

In context: 
- "I'm hungry, let's eat! Any preferences?" 
- "Oh anything's fine, I'm **flexible**."

Comment: *Flexible* is by no means the opposite of picky, not even in your example, especially because one can be picky *and* flexible at the same time (the former doesn't mutually exclude the latter).

Comment: @gented - Agreed.  "Flexible", which can mean you're open to options in this case, typically is still couched in the fact that the flexible person is picky, but there is a little leeway for other options.  You can only be so flexible before you flex too far and "break".

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest:

- **undemanding** (if speaking about food or requirements)
- **casual** (about clothing or attitude in general)

In colloquial speech (bear in mind I am a native *British* English speaker. My colloquialisms may not be quite the same in American English) you may hear:

> "I'm easy"

in response to a question about tastes, likes, dislikes. This conveys a casual attitude, that you have no specific likes or dislikes.

Or:

> "I'm not fussy" (informal)
>   "I'm not particular" (slightly more formal)

Comment: "I'm easy" works well in the US, too. It's commonly heard and general-purpose enough to work in these situations.

Comment: As a 60-yo BrE speaker, "I'm easy" sounds like an Americanism to me.  It is quite possible it has been adopted into BrE though.

Comment: Be careful about using "I'm easy" without supplying immediate context, since it can imply specifically "I am the opposite of picky when it comes to sexual partners."

Comment: Relatively young American here seconding @BryanKrause -- I would never see "I'm easy" used with regards to pickiness in tastes, and it carries a **VERY** heavy sexual connotation (meaning "I will have sex with anything and everything"), especially for women.

Comment: Errr... sure, with no context. If I asked someone "How do you like your eggs?" and they responded with "I'm easy." I'd take it to mean "whatever way you cook them", not "hey lets smash"...

Comment: @Sparksbet Better not tell Lionel Richie (Composer and singer of Easy Like Sunday Morning) about that . The sexual availability usage/meaning is merely elision of the rest of the phrase, i.e. "to have sex with".

Comment: @Adonalsium I personally wouldn't understand the intended meaning in that context either (this thread is the first I've heard of this meaning to be honest) and would assume you wanted your eggs over easy.

Comment: @user46359 I mean, I'm hardly gonna claim "easy" is never used as described in this answer, but I would be *very* hesitant to use it like that -- if a native speaker in her 20s is unfamiliar with using "easy" to mean "not picky", it might go over quite a few other people's heads, and I think it's best to generally tread carefully when it comes to anything with potential sexual connotations (after all, think of the potential confusion with a statement like "we should invite her to dinner; she's easy.")

Comment: +1 undemanding fits best imho

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest [unfussy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfussy).  It was my immediate reaction when I saw the question title.

Comment: I think "not fussy" would sound more natural

Comment: @Melkor Right? I was even starting to say that 'unfussy' would work better with things than people... but even things are 'not fussy' rather than 'unfussy'. I suppose it might work in a parallel structure with some other un- prefixed adjectives, though.

Comment: I hear "not fussed" a lot too, which may be poor English but does sound colloquial for it. "What do you want for your tea?" "(I'm) not fussed". Very much a verbal shrug.

Answer (score 7):

If asked for a general preference, e.g.

> What type of X do you **like**?

the most natural responses to my ears are:

> I'm not [fussy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fussy).
>
> I'm not [picky](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/picky).
>
> I'm [easy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/easy#Adjective). (adjective, sense 6)

Although *easy* can have a sexual connotation, most of the time it won't. You'll get a knowing glance because of the [double entendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre), but people won't accidentally misunderstand.

If directly asked for a choice, e.g.

> What type of X do you **want**?

other possible responses are:

> I don't [mind](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mind#Verb). (verb, sense 3)
>
> I'm not [bothered](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bothered).
>
> I'm not [fussed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fussed).

Answer (score 6):

**Easy**, **easygoing**, and **game** are all good choices and already mentioned.

Since no one posted it yet, though, I'll also throw out **[laid back](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Laid%20back)** or **[laid-back](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laid-back)**. [The *OED* has it in the figurative sense of 'relaxed' since at least 1974](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/105124#eid39898643):

> It's all cheerfully grotty and relaxed in the usual **laid-back** Montreal style.

[Wiktionary is unsourced but claims it goes back to the '50s](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/laid-back#English).

Really, any synonym for 'relaxed' is going to work here with a little context. Some fairly popular recent slang would be **[chill](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chill)** or **[down for whatever](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=down+for+whatever)**. The later can have sexual connotations as a general description, but works just fine in response to a focused question.

> Whaddya wanna eat?
>
> Man, I'm **down for whatever**.

Answer (score 4):

Related to Martin Bonner's and Astralbee's answers, the best single-word antonym I can think of is [**unparticular**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unparticular):

> *adjective*: Not particular; especially not exacting, fastidious, or fussy.

Answer (score 3):

**Relaxed** is another good word: "Don't worry, she's pretty relaxed about food." [Merriam-Webster defines it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relaxed) as "easy of manner" which seems to fit your request.

"Relaxed" also comes up in a search for a [translation of "fünfe gerade sein lassen"](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/f%C3%BCnf+gerade+sein+lassen.html) (literally "let five be even", i.e. don't insist on formalities, don't be fussy, be flexible — the German answer to your question).

Answer (score 2):

A less popular but still sometimes used word is ***catholic*** (lower case "c"):

> 2 : comprehensive, universal; especially : **broad in sympathies, tastes, or interests** - *a catholic taste in music*

<sup>[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catholic)</sup>

Comment: That was new to me. Interesting find. I *knew* Catholics had more fun!

Comment: *Much* less popular and not informal at all. This sense of catholic has to reach all the way around the Roman church to the original Greek sense of 'general', 'universal', 'all-encompassing'. It could definitely work in some tightly honed fiction like Nabokov, though.

Comment: People are likely to misinterpret this word as meaning *more* fussy, not less, based on common beliefs/stereotypes about religious people and especially Catholics.

Comment: @lly I don't know, I've never read Nabokov and I've heard and read this word used in this sense many times over the course of my life. An ngram search suggests this word has fallen out of favor and is *much* less common than "picky" is today. Which I think explains why this word sprang to my mind but seems unusual to others: a large portion of my reading has been science fiction from the 30s - the 50s, when the word was more popular than it is today.

Comment: Even the Creed of the (protestant) Church of England contains the line "... holy, catholic, and apostolic church" so it has had meaning outside of one specific Church for some time.

Comment: While this is the first definition in the dictionary, it is not in common usage with this meaning. Which makes it a misleading answer, particularly for people whose first language is not English. "I'm catholic about food" would be a very puzzling sentence.

Comment: @ajfaraday That sentence wouldn’t puzzle me at all, and if you look you’ll see it wasn’t the first definition in the dictionary I quoted. But I appreciate you explaining your downvote.

Comment: It was first in a google's definition feature, although it isn't if you look for Catholic, with a big C.

Comment: Note that this is pronounced differently, so if given in spoken speech, it's not too difficult to distinguish it from "Catholic". This word appears in the Nicene Creed: "one holy catholic and apostolic Church"

Comment: @Acccumulation FYI I've never pronounced "Catholic" differently from "catholic". If I've heard them pronounced differently, I'm not aware of it. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: @ToddWilcox "Catholic" is pronounced "CATH-lic". "catholic" is pronounced "ca-THOL-ic".

Comment: @Acccumulation The Merriam-Webster link in my answer disagrees with your second pronunciation, but that doesn't mean Merriam-Webster is right. I've never heard "ca-THOL-ic" in my life, and despite all the downvoters, I've heard the word *catholic* used to mean "not picky" many times.

Answer (score 2):

A word that's very similar in meaning to the adjective *picky* would be **finicky**. The opposite of *finicky* then would be [**unfinicky**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unfinicky) which is defined simply as:

> not finicky

You could also consider the word [**unfastidious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfastidious) which, as with *unfinicky*, is simply the opposite of *fastidious*:

> not fastidious: not extremely or excessively careful, selective, difficult to please, etc.

In all honesty though, you would probably be better off sticking to **not finicky** and **not fastidious** rather than the contrived-sounding *unfinicky* and *unfastidious*:

> He's **not finicky** about the food he eats. So, when it comes to food, he's a person that's not very hard to please.
>
> She's **not** very **fastidious** about the clothes she wears. In fact, she buys most of her clothes in second-hand stores.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a special word, but in my experience, the most common antonym for **picky** is **not picky**.

"Where would you like to eat dinner" 
"Oh anywhere is fine, I'm not picky."

"It's easy taking my daughter clothes shopping, she's not picky about brands."

"Did you see the guy Sheila was out with last week? Looks like someone is not very picky..."

Comment: The expression *"not picky"* was already [suggested by @CJ Dennis](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/168035/1694)

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with having six or seven suggestions in a single answer, it's hard to tell what's been posted before, and impossible to vote for just one. Oh well, as a mere human, I am subject to such failings.

Answer (score -3):

I know only two one-word words, but both are rather formal:

- Unpretentious
- Modest

You could also say "not too picky" or "not too demanding".

If about food, you could say "hearty eater".

Comment: I'm not native English speaker, but those two words looks formal and more applicable to clothes than to food, don't they? What about "unfussy"? (I've found that one in the link provided by Tetsujin)

Comment: @RubioRic Neither of those could be applied to taste in food, and "unfussy" is what I was about to suggest!